# Ubuntu Encryption

Tags: encryption

The November 2016 issue of Consumer Reports magazine, on page 36, states that Ubuntu encrypts your hard drive.  Is this a true statement?  Am I correct in assuming that the encryption is done automatically or is some operator action required?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu *can* encrypt your hard drive, if you choose to do it at installation.

Ubiquiti (the installer) will have an option saying "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation":

[image]

Check this box, and your Ubuntu will be installed encrypted. Note that this must be manually selected.

Comment: Just curious, but to enable this _after_ installation, would I have to re-install Ubuntu? Or is there an option to due it on the existing hard drive through a command or application?

Comment: @OwenHines There is a way to enable encryption post-install, but there's no promise that the conversion will work right. You can definitely encrypt just the home directory, but I am aware of no path for full encryption at the moment.